# Does Varnish Handle User Web Sessions

Tags: session, varnish

I've had 2 sysadmins from 2 large hosting organizations tell me that Varnish will handle session sharing between web servers.  I can find nothing online to support this and in fact found [this](https://www.varnish-cache.org/forum/topic/426) where the guy specifically says it does not.  I cannot tell if the guy is a Varnish employee or just a contributor or what.

Just looking for more verification on this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A session allows you to store many things (shopping carts, logged in user, etc), and is commonly identified by a cookie (e.g. `sessionid`). A web server knows how to get a session using this sessionid (and can access/update your shopping cart), but varnish only handles cookies. Varnish can do load-balanced lookups to backends, regardless of the cookie values or based on some rules (you need to write you own varnish config).

However, a challenge in session sharing between web servers is whether a web server can access sessions created/updated by another web server. In many Java Web Containers, sessions are by default stored in memory (of only one web server), with load balancers implementing some kind of 'sticky session' mechanism (sending a user with a session to a specific back-end all the time, can be easily setup with varnish). Another option is to store the (serialized) session values in a shared database, so they can be retrieved by any backend (and will keep working if a web server goes down). A third option is to completely serialize the session into a cookie and stop using sessionids, but this is complex (limited size, bandwidth, security requires some signing mechanism, but scaling is great).

All approaches have advantages and disadvantages. You have to choose, varnish supports any option but will not 'automagically' do what you want, so prepare to write a bit of varnish configuration...

If you would describe how you want to load balance, or what you try to achieve, you could get a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I had already confirmed that it doesn't do what I really want it to do out of the box.  The sysadmin that said it supported web sessions misunderstood my question.  To be complete, I need that when / if a app server goes down, customers don't even know it and their session carries over to the next machine.  We're going to use Terracotta for that.

Comment: That's great and all but it's trivial to setup 2 repcached (patched memcached) services that store and replicate sessions for PHP. Using a database isn't that hard for a developer. I've tested this and run it in production. I have issues if I don't fine tune and manage memory from time to time so there's some maintenance. Guess it depends on your stack and budget.